# Why does the Cygwin 'ls' command send UDP packets?

Tags: cygwin, spyware, anti-spyware

I have Cygwin installed and noticed that since my company started using CrowdStrike Falcon for malicious behavior detection, running simple commands like 'ls', 'grep', etc, takes way longer than it used to take. Like 2 to 10 seconds for a simple 'ls' command in a directory with only 4 files. But it still runs, it just takes a long time to spit out its results (which it does suddenly at the end of the 2 to 10 second delay).

At first I thought perhaps CrowdStrike Falcon was testing every program that ever runs (every time it runs) in a sandbox VM for several seconds to make sure it doesn't do anything malicious... which it may be doing, but... my own C++ programs written on Visual Studio don't take that long to run.

So I started wondering, is Cygwin going out over the network even when I run 'ls' on a local directory? So I, not knowing a lot about IP traffic logging, downloaded TCPView by Sysinternals (from the real https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals website, not from any of the various other websites that gladly provide a copy of Sysinternals' tools along with their own spyware tacked on for good measure).

With TCPView running and sorted on the PID column in descending order hoping that gives me a better chance of seeing newer processes at the top, I ran C:\cygwin\bin\ls from a Windows command prompt. Nothing happened for about 5 seconds, then all of the sudden a new line showed up and another two lines showed up about a second later with the process name "ls.exe", showing UDP traffic.

Why would Cygwin's ls.exe need to send UDP packets when my current directory was on my local C: drive, and I ran ls with no arguments?

Comment: domain users so some infos are requested to the domain controller ? Try running `cygserver` to cache information  and reduce the requests to the domain controller https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html

Comment: @matzeri - I'm sorry, I don't understand... What is the domain controller? Is there a Cygwin domain conroller, or is that unrelated to Cygwin but Cygwin must deal with it? I am on a domain, that's true.

Comment: `ls -l` show the users owner of files and their groups. To know the name of the users the cygwin process can ask them to your domain controller (every domain have one)

Comment: @matzeri - I was only executing the `ls` command without any arguments; would it still need to contact the domain controller?

Comment: Question: to which address the data are sent ? Eventually your own computer ?

Comment: @matzeri - OK, now I'm wondering if the time it takes to execute the command (and whether or not it sends UDP packets) is dependent on where I am in the C: filesystem. I closed the cmd window I was using yesterday, and now I don't remember where I was when I was running `ls`. But now I'm running it and it only takes a second or so to run, and it's not showing UDP connections in TCPView anymore. So maybe it depends on what directory I'm in.

Comment: But if I recall correctly, the remote address was a 10.x.x.x address that was not my own machine. (Some entries in TCPView give the remote address as either my unqualified machine name, my machine name qualified with the domain name, or 'localhost'. The `ls` entries yesterday had none of those.)